# python: pandas - order of data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following code to output a dataFrame:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({"id":id_test, "hum":y_pred})
output.to_csv("myOutput.csv", index=False)
```

Then in myOutput.csv, I got `hum` as the first column, `id` as the second column. Is there a way to make `id` the first column instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reorder the columns:

```
output.ix[:,['id','hum']].to_csv("myOutput.csv", index=False)
```

Because you used a dict as the data, the column order is not necessarily the same order as the key creation order in the dict